# Disable editing in text view

Tags: ios7, uitextview

I'm using Xcode coding an ios7 app, whenever I try to make a text view it is editable by the user. How can I fix this so it can not be editable? It is editable in the iPhone simulator, what property do I need to change to disable this and where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the textView in the storyboard (if you created it in the storyboard), then you can open the attributes inspector on the right and there is a checkbox that says editable. If it was not created in the storyboard, then there is a property

```
 textView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: In story board I unchecked the editable box and cleaned the debug files, but it is still editable in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

//.h

```
@interface YourViewController:UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UItextView *textView;
@end
```

//.m

```
 -(void) viewDidload
{
   _textView.delegate =self;
}

- (BOOL)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, click on UITextField in storyboard and there is a property called behaviour editable: remove the tick than and build.